# Google sheets script Exceeded maximum execution time

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, time, limit, stock

I wrote a script to import stock data from a csv file stored in Google Drive to an existing google sheet.

In one function I'm doing this for multiple csv files. Unfortunately I get "Exceeded maximum execution time" sometimes, but not all the time.

Do you have an idea how I can boost performance on this:

```
   //++++++++++++++ SPY +++++++++++++++++++

var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("SPY.csv").next();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());


//Create new temporary sheet
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("SPY-Import");

if (yourNewSheet != null) {
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
}

yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
yourNewSheet.setName("SPY-Import");

//Import
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

//Copy from temporary sheet to destination
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A:B').activate();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SPY'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('\'SPY-Import\'!A:B').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);


//Delete temporary sheet

// Get Spreadsheet Object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// Get target sheet object
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SPY-Import");
// Delete
 spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your script in your question and `In one function I'm doing this for multiple csv files.`? Your script in your question is run in the loop?

Comment: I'm not running it in a loop, but only because of missing programming skills.
Therefore, the posted snipped is copied multiple times in this function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, your script in your question is copied and run several scripts at one execution. If my understanding is correct, how much times are you using your script in one execution?

Comment: And also, can I ask you about the change parts when you use the copied script? In your case, those are 3 parts of `SPY.csv` of `DriveApp.getFilesByName("SPY.csv")`, `SPY-Import` of `activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("SPY-Import")` and `SPY` of `(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SPY')`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To make it clear: To posted snipped is copied for different stock quote in one function. I just posted this part because of its length.

It runs around 4-5 Minutes and than I get the "exceeded time limit" error.

Comment: I would like to confirm my understanding for your situation and goal. 1. You have several CSV files like `SPY.csv`. 2. Your Spreadsheet has the several sheet corresponding to each CSV file like `SPY`. 3. You want to put the values from the CSV data to the Spreadsheet. In this case, you want to put the values of the column "A" and "B" of the CSV data. 4. You want to reduce the process cost of your script. I understood your goal like this. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes your understanding is 100% correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm that my understanding was correct. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- You have several CSV files like `SPY.csv`.
- Your Spreadsheet has the several sheet corresponding to each CSV file like `SPY`.
- You want to put the values from the CSV data to the Spreadsheet.

  - You want to put the values of the column "A" and "B" of the CSV data.
- In your current situation, you copied the script in your question several times and run them by changing the csv filename and sheet name.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your script. I understood your goal like this.

#### Modification points:

- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is used several times. And, `activate()` is used several times.

  - I think that in your case, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be declared one time, and `activate()` is not required to be used.
- In order to copy the CSV data to Spreadsheet, the CSV data is put to a temporal sheet and the required values are copied to the destination sheet.

  - In this case, I think that the CSV data is directly put to the destination sheet by processing on the array.

I think that above points lead to the reduction of process cost. When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script and prepare the variable of `obj`. When you run the script, the CSV data is retrieved and processed, and then, the values are put to the Spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var obj = [
    {filename: "SPY.csv", sheetname: "SPY"},
    {filename: "###.csv", sheetname: "###"},
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ];
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  obj.forEach(({filename, sheetname}) => {
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
      if (sheet) {
//        sheet.clearContents(); // Is this requierd in your situation?
        var csv = DriveApp.getFileById(file.next().getId()).getBlob().getDataAsString();
        var values = Utilities.parseCsv(csv).map(([a, b]) => [a, b]);
        sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8
- I'm not sure about your CSV data. So when `Utilities.parseCsv(csv)` cannot be used, please use the delimiter.
- In this modification, Spreadsheet service is used. If above modified script occurs the same error of `Exceeded maximum execution time`, please tell me. At that time, I would like to propose the sample script using Sheets API.

#### References:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you so much for your solution and the great explanation!! It works really well and makes total sense to me! The "clearContents()" is not nessecary in my case, but thanks for putting it there. 

For your info: I built a Python script to download the csv data from Yahoo Finance. In the next step I will try to find a way to run this script from google sheets in order to fully automate is on a daily basis with a time trigger.